# PHP Multi-cURL requests delayed until timeout

Tags: php, curl, php-5.4, curl-multi

**Summary**

I have some PHP 5.4 code which fetches a batch of Facebook/Instagram photos in parallel using multi curl. This code has been working for years, and nothing has changed as far as I can tell.

I add multiple curl requests to a 'multi' request. Each curl request gets a `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`. The problem I'm seeing is that, all of a sudden, some of my requests don't complete until this timeout is reached (no matter what timeout I set).

**Code**

I do something like this (simplified):

```
do {
    while (CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM === curl_multi_exec($mh, $running));

    // Wait for activity on any curl-connection (optional, reduces CPU)
    curl_multi_select($mh);

    // a request was just completed -- find out which one
    while($done = curl_multi_info_read($mh))
    {
        $completedCurlRequest = $done['handle'];

        //save the file
        do_some_work(completedCurlRequest);

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $completedCurlRequest);
    }
} while ($running);
```

I use this script to run batches of about 40 parallel requests to fetch some images (from Facebook). Most of them take about 500ms to complete. However, a few of the requests "hang" (until the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`) before they arrive.

Basically the `curl_multi_select` step takes the entire timeout. Or, if I remove that `curl_multi_select` line, the outer loop spins (burning CPU) until the timeout.

**Considerations**

- It doesn't matter what the timeout is - if I set the timeout to 30s,
  they arrive after 30 seconds, If I set the timeout to 1s, they arrive
  after 1s!
- This is a really sudden change that does not correlate with any code
  release - it was all working fine up until 30th Jan 2019, but on the
  31st it suddenly stopped working.
- This isn't easy to reproduce, as it only affects an image once. If I
  repeat it for a batch of images I already fetched, it works fine the
  next time round.
- It affects both Facebook and Instagram images, so I think the issue
  must be to do with my code or my server (and not Facebook or
  Instagram), as they wouldn't have both changed something
  simultaneously.

**Questions**

1. Am I doing something wrong in my use of multi-curl that could cause this? (but if so, what's changed?)
2. Have Facebook and Instagram changed anything that might cause this?
3. Could something on my server have changed to trigger this?
4. How can I debug this?

**Update**
Here is the what I get back from a slow request when it finally completes:

INFO

```
"content_type": "image/jpeg",
"http_code": 200,
"header_size": 377,
"request_size": 180,
"total_time": 15.001012,    //<----- Total time == CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
"namelookup_time": 0.007149,
"connect_time": 0.12018,
"pretransfer_time": 0.441911,
"size_download": 40714,
"speed_download": 2714,
"download_content_length": -1,   //<------Not set
```

HEADER

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: image/jpeg
x-haystack-needlechecksum: 3529661797
timing-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=1209600, no-transform
date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 14:04:17 GMT
access-control-expose-headers: X-FB-CEC-Video-Limit
```

It is missing the `content-length` header, but that always seems to be the case the first time a file is fetched. Only 1 or 2 of the 50 parallel requests are slow, yet all of the requests are missing their content length headers.

If I fetch the same file again, it is much quicker, and I do see content length being set this time

INFO

```
"download_content_length": 52721,
```

HEADER

```
content-length: 52721
```

Comment: `they wouldn't have both changed something simultaneously.` - yes that's very likely. Facebook owns Instagram, it's likely that they run on the same image CDN stack, which is likely related to your problem - when this happen, does that curl handle recieve a `Content-Length` header? also do you use CURLOPT_ENCODING? in which case, what encoding was chosen by the server? (aka what did the response's `Content-Encoding` header contain? if that header is president in the result at all)

Comment: Thanks @hanshenrik, no I don't set CURLOPT_ENCODING. I will dump all the fields in the response, but what am I looking for exactly?

Comment: you're looking for a `Content-Length` header, if that header is missing, it could explain why the download is so damn slow. also check if this makes a difference: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'identity');`

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik - I've updated my question based on your suggestion. Content-length is indeed missing, but that is the case for successful requests too. I've tried your CURLOPT_ENCODING suggestion but that doesn't change anything.  Perhaps you can give me some hints as to what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current theory is that there is a bug in Facebook fileserver that means the connection is sometimes not being closed even though the data has been sent, so the connection stays open until the timeout. In the absence of the (optional) content-length header being sent by Facebook's fileserver, cURL can't know if the payload is complete, and so hangs.

My current solution is to 'prime' the fileserver by first making a request for the image without a body, like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
```

This is a pretty quick process, since there is no image being returned. I actually do this in the background using asynchronous multi curl, so I can get on with doing some other processing.

After priming the fileserver, subsequent requests for the files are even quicker than before, as the content-length is known.

This is a bit of a clumsy approach, but in the absence of any response from Facebook so far I'm not sure what else to do.